# linux shell: prepend or append text to next line after matching line

Tags: linux, shell, replace, sed, append

Using a shell script in Linux (bash or csh). I would like to find all lines that match a given text pattern, and for each line prepend or append (depending on the application) text to the following line.

For example, for a file containing lines like this:

```
HEADER 1
 12345

HEADER 2
 12345

HEADER 1
 12345

HEADER 2
 12345
```

If I am searching for "HEADER 1", and would like to append the text "ABCDE", the output would be this:

```
HEADER 1
 12345 ABCDE

HEADER 2
 12345

HEADER 1
 12345 ABCDE

HEADER 2
 12345
```

I also have cases where I would want the ABCDE preceding 12345.

I have been trying to understand the usage of sed for this purpose, but I feel stymied. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sed '/HEADER 1/{n;s/$/ ABCDE/}' input.txt
```

---

This is the logic:

```
for each line in 'input.txt'    
    if line matches /HEADER 1/
        read next line
        append string ' ABCDE'
    endif    
endfor
```

Comment: For appending, this works and makes sense when I align with the sed documentation. By extension I expect this to work for prepending:

    {n;s/^/foo /}

Comment: use `s/^/ABCDE /` to prepend.

Comment: How would you modify this to handle a path variable with slashes (e.g. MYPATH=/home/user/tools)

sed '/HEADER 1/{n;s/$/ $MYPATH/}' input.txt obviously doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

sed is an excellent tool for simple substitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk for portability, extensibility, simplicty, readability, etc., etc.:

```
$ awk 'found{print $0, "ABCDE"; found=0; next} {print} /HEADER 1/{found=1}' file
HEADER 1
 12345 ABCDE

HEADER 2
 12345

HEADER 1
 12345 ABCDE

HEADER 2
 12345
```

and to pre-pend is just the obvious switch the order of "ABCDE" and $0:

```
$ awk 'found{print "ABCDE", $0; found=0; next} {print} /HEADER 1/{found=1}' file
HEADER 1
ABCDE  12345

HEADER 2
 12345

HEADER 1
ABCDE  12345

HEADER 2
 12345
```

If you are using sed language constructs other than s, g, p (with -n) then you are using the wrong tool as all other sed language constructs became obsolete in the mid-1970s when awk was invented.

If you doubt that, try modifying a sed script that produces the above output to do anything else, e.g. print a count of how many times it's added ABCDE at the end of each line it does that on. Here's awk:

```
$ awk 'found{print $0, "ABCDE", ++count; found=0; next} {print} /HEADER 1/{found=1}' file
HEADER 1
 12345 ABCDE 1

HEADER 2
 12345

HEADER 1
 12345 ABCDE 2

HEADER 2
 12345
```

I dread to think what the sed would look like to do something that simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you're confused on the general text-piping linux applications, I would recommend going through [this exercise on the Learn Linux the Hard Way course](http://nixsrv.com/llthw/ex8). Should take 4-5 minutes and help quite a bit.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I will gladly read through that. I would like to build up my understanding of sed, awk, and others.